# Morse Homology of $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, morse-theory

I'm trying to compute the homology of $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ using the following Morse function. First, consider $f:S^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ taking $(x,y,z) \mapsto y^2 + 2z^2$. This can be shown to be Morse on $S^2$ with critical points $(\pm 1,0,0)$ of index $0$, $(0, \pm1, 0)$ of index $1$ and $(0,0,\pm 1)$ of index $2$.

This function descends to a function $g: \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with three critical points $a=[1:0:0]$ (index $0$), $b=[0:1:0]$ (index $1$), $c=[0:0:1]$ (index $2$).

By considering dimensions, we immediately see that all pseudo-gradients will satisfy the Smale condition. Also, there are two trajectories from $c$ to $b$ and two from $b$ to $a$. Thus, with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients, the homology is: $H_0 = H_1 = H_2 = \mathbb{Z}/2$.

However, I'm having trouble with orientations and thus computing over $\mathbb{Z}$. How should we orient the stable and unstable manifolds and thus, determine an orientation on the moduli spaces of trajectories?

There is a question on this on math.SE but it uses a different function and unfortunately, I don't understand the given answer. I know the homology is independent of the chosen function but I'll like to understand computations starting from a concrete Morse function.

Comment: You orient them arbitrarily and check that the result is independent of choice. However you orient them, there will be two trajectories from $c$ to $b$ of the same sign, and the trajectories from $b$ to $a$ will have opposite sign. Probably it is easiest to see all of this "upstairs" on $S^2$.

Comment: Certainly that is the result we expect from singular homology. But looking upstairs in $S^2$ doesn't seem to help because there is only one trajectory between a critical point of index 2 and one of index 1. It's after identifying antipodal points that we get two trajectories from c to b.

Comment: The involution upstairs identifies the two critical points of index 1 and 2; there are four trajectories from index 2 to index 1 upstairs, and two of them are identified by the involution. A choice of orientations of stable and unstable manifolds downstairs lifts to one upstairs that is invariant under the involution, and so you may count these trajectories with their orientations upstairs (only choosing one per equivalence class). You don't need them to go to the same point; you just need to be able to count them.

Comment: Have a look at this https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0411465.pdf

Comment: Mabye take a look at https://www.merry.io/students/morse-theory/ example 6.3 - there I basically filled in the details to the post you mentioned and gave a full proof.